# Testing production APNS certificates using adhoc build - I broke something but don't know what

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app store app that uses push notifications. I broke something along the way and I can't figure out what. My new versions are not receiving push notifications while old versions did. My backend server uses APNS production certificates.

To test what I broke, I am trying to build an adhoc ipa of my app - after generating the IPA and installing on my phone, its not receiving push either

Screenshots below - what am I missing?

The resulting ipa is not receiving push from APNS using production certs

My adhoc profile:
[image: My adhoc profile]

My code signing setup:
[image]

My push is on:
[image]

Exporting as adhoc:
[image]
[image]

Entitlements:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the entitlements?

Comment: is it possible that development deviceTokens were sent before? I mean did you run the code on your device with development code signing. This would prevent that specific device from registering production deviceTokens.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have no idea what happened, so I went ahead and regenerated everything starting from the certs and now its working again. I wish Apple APNS were as simple as GCM

Comment: True that my friend.